Curve Text AND be able to export to Roblox Studio
I'm modelling various signs for a Roblox Studio project and I've just learned about different ways to use text to achieve this. One of the signs I'm making involves text going in a circle (like a logo of sorts). I've watched a few videos that suggest to make the text follow a bezier circle and this works however the problem is exporting the model to Roblox Studio results in an error since the Circle isn't a mesh. On the other hand, converting the bezier circle into a mesh results in the text no longer following the curve. Isthere a way I can "lock" the text into its curved shape or be able to export the model as needed?


Well, I don't exactly know how you have made the text follow the circle (and you don't show it in the question just in case this information might be helpful for finding an answer), but usually it should be enough to select the text and press Ctrl+A > Apply > Visual Geometry to Mesh and that's it. Then you don't need the circle anymore and it can be deleted. You just cannot change the text or curving anymore - but this functionality would not be transferable to Roblox anyway.

Yeah, your problem is that you're converting the Circle to a Mesh, you need to convert the Text object. The circle is just a "helper" object to give the text a guide for its' shape. But you wouldn't export that most likely.

Sorry I didn't clarify what method I used. I used the follow curve option on the font. I've tried Applying Visual Geometry to Mesh and it seems to have worked. Thank You!

I was just asking because if for example you used Geometry Nodes and the letters were just instances, they would disappear with applying the modifier. You would have to Realizes Instances first to get "real" geometry.

There is a quite simple way how to apply all modifiers at once and also make curves to mesh object with a single shortcut, not only for the object in your question but all objects that have some procedural mesh:
Ctrl+A > Apply > Visual Geometry to Mesh

But depending on how you generated the object you want to convert into a mesh, the result might not be what you expect. In the follwing image, there are two texts along a curve. The one on the top is made with Text object and a Curve modifier, the one below is made with a more complex setup in a Geometry Nodes modifier:

If I now hit Ctrl+A I get the following result: the top text is still there, it is now a mesh object and no longer connected to the curve but kept its deformation. The bottom text has disappeared, although the object is still there. You can still the origin point, but it is now an empty mesh.

This is because the text generated by the Geometry Nodes modifier was made of instances. A Geometry Nodes modifier will only output real meshes when you apply it. So for instances you have to use a Realize Instances node, the best is to place it directly as last node before the Group Output if you are planning to apply the modifier and want to make sure all instances are converted (and on current versions make sure Realize All is checked). However, everything that is not a mesh object will disappear even if you realized the instances. Because things like curves and volumes etc. are no mesh objects.

